# Ipod Touch not mounted

Tags: usb, ipod

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 in a Dell XPS15.  When plugging in the Ipod it charges but when trying to mount it I can't find it anywhere.

I've done a dmesg | grep usb before plugging the Ipod and I can't see any errors, but when plugged in I see:

```
[ 2133.483377] usb 2-1.6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[ 2133.670208] cdc_ether 2-1.6:1.6: wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:80:37:ec:02:00
[ 2755.346215] usb 3-4: new high speed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 4
[ 2755.376509] usb 3-4: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 512 microframes
[ 2755.381982] usb 3-4: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 512 microframes
[ 2755.382093] usb 3-4: ERROR: Endpoint drop flag = 0, add flag = 1, and endpoint is not disabled.
[ 2755.394808] usb 3-4: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 512 microframes
[ 2755.394943] usb 3-4: ERROR: Endpoint drop flag = 0, add flag = 1, and endpoint is not disabled.
```

I don't have any clue how can I try to make the Ipod works because the USB seems to be working fine for other devices (mice, camera,...)

Any thoughts or guide about what can I do?

Edit: If it helps, when doing: `lsusb | grep Apple` I get:

```
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 05ac:1299 Apple, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the iPod touch doesn't support USB mass-storage, so it won't appear as a disk: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1380?viewlocale=en_US

From what I can see you should be able to use it via [Clementine](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/wiki/PortableDevices) or Amarok though

If you're willing to jailbreak there's some useful information here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPod#iPhone.2FiPod_Touch

Comment: If it doesn't support USB. How I am supposed to even see it with Clementine or Amarok? It doesn't even seem the Ipod is recognized by the system...

Comment: It does connect via USB, it just doesn't support USB mass-storage (the same kind of protocol used by flash drives, portable HDDs etc.). http://www.libimobiledevice.org is used to support the proprietary Apple protocols for interfacing with iDevices

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I'm not able to see my Ipod with Clementine.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils` and then `ideviceinfo` with the Touch plugged in

Comment: Thanks again for answering the comment. I've done what asked and with the Ipod plugged in (I've tried both locked and unlocked) I get: "No device found, is it plugged in?" :/

Comment: On the off chance that it's a permissions issue try `sudo ideviceinfo`. The imobiledevice FAQ suggests: rebooting, removing the passcode on the device (when connecting for the first time) and trying a different USB port. Beyond that there's not much more I can suggest as I've never used an Apple device on Linux

Answer (score 0):

you can mount it using ifuse:

```
mkdir /mnt/ipod
ifuse /mnt/ipod
ls -l /mnt/ipod
ls /mnt/ipod
AirFair  Books                                DCIM       iTunes_Control  Photos     Recordings
Airlock  com.apple.itdbprep.postprocess.lock  Downloads  PhotoData       Purchases
```

You can use it as mass storage, but it's still not visible from Rythmbox, tried Clementine but a black error window appears and Clementine fails