# Ubuntu doesn't mount iPod

Tags: 13.10, usb, mount, ipod

I cannot access my iPod files even though the iPod is found by Ubuntu.

Output of `lsusb`

`Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:129e Apple, Inc. iPod Touch 4.Gen`

Output of `dmesg`

`[  118.991968] usb 2-1.2: Product: iPod
[  118.991973] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[  118.991978] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: f8c18467afcfbf51bb4109357a1e38a17a4af67f`

I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is iPod touch doesn't support USB mass-storage, you can find some answers here:

[Ipod Touch not mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93540/ipod-touch-not-mounted?rq=1)

Comment: I know but I can't seem to get it to work with CLemitime either