# Ipod not recognised in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ipod

KUbuntu does not recognize my I Pod does anyone know how I can rectify this?.

I have just installed it but have no knowledge of how to rectify this.

Comment: Following question may be of some help [ubuntu doesn't mount ipod](http://askubuntu.com/questions/414534/ubuntu-doesnt-mount-ipod)

Answer (score 0):

Ipods don't support USB storage so you must sync them like you do to Itunes.

The default music player Amarok should sync if you open it with the Ipod connected but I could be wrong

For a better solution (in my opinion) I recommend GTKPOD, this is a program designed exclusively to manage your I pod, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```

Then just search gtkpod in start menu, it should meet all your Ipod needs and is like Itunes, [here is there website](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home)